# anova and tukey reporting

Tags: anova, reporting, tukey-hsd-test

I have an ANOVA with a numerical score as the DP and a category as an IV:
`model = aov(score~group, data = dat)` And then I run a Tukey: `TukeyHSD(model)`. I get the output:

```
                diff       lwr       upr     p adj
no-maybe   6.4962406 -1.667561 14.660042 0.1473910
yes-maybe  5.6575851  1.191148 10.124022 0.0087644
yes-no    -0.8386555 -7.959717  6.282406 0.9582525
```

But i need to report mean and SD, how can I get this information?

Edit: I already tried that agricolae package but it won't load for me

Comment: If its means and SDs of the three groups you want, why not just get then separately. _Centers_ of intervals ought to be group sample means (upr - lwr)/2.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to get the SD. Is it literally the subset of 2/3 of the groups for each test? Like if i make 3 subsets for the 3 combinations I can get the SD from R, or work it out myself? I wasn't sure if there was more processing in the test. It seems too simple so i wasnt sure if i was missing something, and wanted to get the information from R to be confident in it.

Comment: Confused about what SDs you' re supposed to report, and why.

Comment: I took the format from here:[link](http://statistics-help-for-students.com/How_do_I_report_a_1_way_between_subjects_ANOVA_in_APA_style.htm#.Xn5WzdNKg0o), tbh i'm new to this, so i was just following the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install the agricolae package and did it this way